# Referencing a property in a object model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a converter that use to get the property from my MainWindow class this way:

```
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        MainWindow mainWindow = (MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow;
        ObservableCollection<string[]> selectedItems = mainWindow.SelectedLayerItems; // A collection of layer items
```

But now my MainWindow has been merged with another project and is reorganized into a mvvm object called 'MapView' and can be constructed for different uses.
My question is how can I access the MapView Object from the converter to get the MapView.SelectedLayerItems?

Comment: You don't access any Views from a converter. You're mixing completely different concepts here. What do you need this for?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        dynamic mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        ObservableCollection<string[]> selectedItems = mainWindow.SelectedLayerItems; // A collection of layer items
```